# Handling touch event logic in Subview or ViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller

I have a series of UIView subclasses that are added as subviews. Each subview can be dragged and dropped. When they are dropped (touchesEnded), I need to run a method in the viewController to do some work. I currently have the touchEvents handled in each subview class. Should I be handling these touch events in the viewController or should I be passing a pointer to the parent viewController as a property of each class I have added as subviews?

UPDATE: Or is this a job for NotificationCenter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIViewController is a subclass of UIResponder, and instances are automatically inserted in the responder chain behind the views they control. As a result, you can implement the same event methods in subclasses of UIViewController as in subclasses of UIView, and they will 'just work'; that is, they'll be called automatically.

So if your view controller needs to respond to `-touchesEnded:withEvent:`, just implement the method directly in your UIViewController subclass. If the view also needs to do something in response to the event, you can always send it a message from within your `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` (or whatever) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You might try delegating your desired touch handling event from your uiview subclass to the uiviewcontroller using a delegate protocol.  The view controller can set itself as delegate as it instantiates or adds each subview.

In MVC paradigm, if you want to handle a touch that's specific to a V view's internals (button appearance/location), then you might want to handle that touch in the V view, but if the touch effects some state outside the view (it's position in a bigger window, etc.) you might want to pass handling that touch up to the C controller to set state in the M model.